# Python if statements and truth value testing for non compsci background

Tags: python, boolean, bitwise-operators, logical-operators, truthiness

This aims to be a self answered question after a few hours of digging, I found this thought process may prove useful to others who also may not have come from a formal compsci background.

This all started from confusion over why one particular if statement was being entered.

```
>>>if (2 & 2):
...    print("true")
true
```

Why was this if statement being entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous use of if statements were all quite straightforward, so I took it for granted and with the understanding that only a boolean True would result in the entering of an if statement. What constitutes a boolean True, was not so obvious to me after running into this if statement. This is surely obvious to those with a compsci background, but I never really dug into how if statements determined if the argument was a boolean True or not. For example, if (5 > 2) --> True just makes sense to anyone with at least an elementary-school math background, so I took it for granted. On the contrary, if (2) --> True, does not seem too obvious to a non compsci specialist.

For example

```
>>>2 & 2
2
>>> 2 == True
False
>>>if (2):
...    print("true")
true
```

Why was the if statement entered despite 2 & 2 evaluating to an int value of 2? Why was the if statement entered if given the int value 2 even though 2 itself is not == True? This was the first I had seen this type of behavior and it lead me to understand from various other stack overflow questions that the if statement is not evaluating if the int value of 2 == True, but instead evaluating bool(2) == True, which is in fact True.

Again, if you come from a comp sci background, I'm sure this is all very obvious, but even the idea of bool(2) and "truth value testing" as a phrase was new to me, so adding this on to the binary logical operators caused me a fair bit of confusion at first. For example:

```
>>>2 & 4
0
>>>if (2 & 4):
...    print("true")
>>>bin(2 & 4)
'0b0'
>>>if ('0b0'):
...    print("true")
true
>>>if (0b0):
...    print("true")
>>>bool(0)
False
>>>bool(0b0)
False
>>>bool(b'0')
True
>>>bool(bin(0))
True
```

At first, with the misunderstanding that the if statements were evaluating if the argument == True, the above examples seemed quite illogical, as I thought a binary 1 should result in True and binary 0 should result in False. I had no idea why integer values above 1, in either int or binary form should return True.

After reading through the python docs for [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#truth) I see a few examples of objects that are considered false. Here, and rather obviously, it makes sense why bool(0) and bool(0b0) returns False. The opposite though, for bool(b'0') and bool(bin(0)), where this seems to return True. Why is this? Because [bin()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=bin#bin) returns a ***string*** representation of the number, as is b'0' (a string) not an actual binary value (like 0b0), and since these strings are not empty strings, but rather filled with the characters representing zero, it evaluates to True (See third bullet point of [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#truth)).

I gave a few examples of non-obvious (to me) truth evaluation tests, and why they do actually make logical sense. Hope this helps others who may be mystified by the seemingly (to me) lesser common uses of the if statement.

Comment: Your penultimate paragraph is wrong. `b11` is binary 3, a number (as is `b0`). `b'11'` is a bytestring of two characters, similar to the string `'11'`, and has nothing to do with binary numbers. `bin(0)` indeed results in the string representation, `'0b0'`. All non-empty strings - including bytestrings - are truthy, while empty ones are falsy. `bool()` does not return a string representation of anything - it returns either `True` or `False`, depending if the argument is truthy or falsy. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/240443) for a helpful table of falsy values.

Comment: Notably, `bool(b'0')` is `True` because `b'0'` is a non-empty bytestring, and not a zero number - that would be `0b0`. Note also that `0b0` is very different from `'0b0'`. Also note that the concept of "truthy" and "falsy" values differs among programming languages. PHP has a much looser definition of falsy values than Python, Ruby a much stricter one, while languages like Java don't have the concept of "truthy" vs "falsy", and their `if` condition must be a proper boolean.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you for your input, and references to other interpretations of truthy from other languages. I'm not sure what is "wrong" about the 2nd to last paragraph. I'm happy to update it, but don't see exactly what you are referencing to be incorrect. I make no reference to b11 there. I think I am making the same point as your 2nd comment when I explain that "Because bool() returns a string representation of the number, not an actual binary value, and since the string is not an empty string, but rather filled with the characters representing zero, it evaluates to True"

Comment: I stated what’s wrong: “`bool()` returns a string representation”. It’s `bin()` that does that. The rest was a comment on your examples (in particular, the implication that `b’11’` should be a binary number, or that `’0b0'` is any kind of a number).

Comment: @Amadan ok, yes! Thank you. I had the doc link to bin(), but bool() in the hyperlink header was a typo. Thank you for pointing that out. I also updated the truthy examples in the last code section to make this clearer.